# `lvs -a` — filtering by name with regex

Tags: regular-expression, lvm

Is it possible to filter output of `lvs -a` using lvs command (I know that it is possible with grep, however I look for some approach with lvm only).

I mean listing only snapshosts and/or filter by name (regex or simple pattern).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `--select` option to filter on any number of criteria; for example, on the LV name:

```
sudo lvs -a --select 'lv_name =~ yourregex'
```

Run `lvs --select help` to see the full list of operators and fields you can use.